# How to find parsing error with ParseKit framework

Tags: objective-c, parsekit

I was wondering if there were a way to get back how far into an assembly a PKParser has parsed before encountering a syntax error.

reference: http://parsekit.com/

I'm using a grammar that basically describes a prefix notation expression language.

For example:

given your standard prefix notation expression grammar and a string "(+ a - b c))"
I'd like to retrieve that [(,+,a] where matched, so I can give the user some idea of where to look to fix their error, but the completeMatchFor and bestMatchFor don't return anything I can use to find this info.

Ideally I'd like to say that a '(' was expected, but it's not necessary for a grammar as simple as what I'm using.

From the book mentioned as the user manual, it seemed as if I would need to create a custom parser for this, but I was hoping that maybe I'd simply missed something in the framework.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

There are two features in ParseKit which can be used to help provide user-readable hints describing parse errors encountered in input.

1. `-[PKParser bestMatchFor:]`
2. The `PKTrack` class

It sounds like you're aware of the `-bestMatchFor:` method even if it's not doing what you expect in this case.

I think the `PKTrack` class will be more helpful here. As described in [Metsker's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201719622), `PKTrack` is exactly like `PKSequence` except that its subparsers are required, and an error is thrown (with a helpful error message) when all of its subparsers are not matched.

So here's a grammar for your example input:

```
@start         = '(' expr ')' | expr;
expr           = ('+' | '-') term term;
term           = '(' expr ')' | Word;
```

Any productions listed contiguously are a Sequence -- but could instead be a Track.

The benefit of changing these Sequences to be Tracks is that an `NSException` will be thrown with a human-readable parse error message if the input doesn't match. The downside is that you must now wrap all usages of your factory-generated parser in a try/catch block to catch these Track exceptions.

The problem currently (or before now, at least) is that the `PKParserFactory` never produced a parser using Tracks. Instead, it would always use Sequences.

So I've *just* added a new option in head of trunk at [Google Code](http://parsekit.googlecode.com/) (you'll need to udpate).

```
#define USE_TRACK 0
```

in

```
PKParserFactory.m
```

It's `0` by default. If you change this define to `1`, Tracks will be used instead of Sequences. So given the grammar above and invalid input like this:

```
(+ a - b c))
```

and this client code:

```
NSString *g = // fetch grammar above
PKParser *p = [[PKParserFactory factory] parserFromGrammar:g assembler:self];
NSString *s = @"(+ a - b c))";

@try {
    PKAssembly *res = [p parse:s];
    NSLog(@"res %@", res);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Parse Error:%@", exception);
}
```

you will get a nice-ish human-readable error:

```
Parse Error:

After : ( + a
Expected : Alternation (term)
Found : -
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm wrestling with this issue too. In order for `-bestMatchFor:` to be useful in identifying error conditions, there should be methods in `PKAssembly`'s public interface indicating if there are more tokens/characters to be parsed. `-completeMatchFor:` is able to determine error state because it has access to the private `-hasMore` method. Perhaps `PKAssembly`'s `-hasMore` method should be public.

I looked at `PKTrack` but since I want to handle errors programmatically, it wasn't useful to me.

My conclusion is I either write my own custom Track parser or I alter the framework and expose `-hasMore`. Are there other ways to handle errors?

Until I figure out a better way to detect errors, I've added the following to the file containing the implementation of my custom parser:

```
@interface PKAssembly ()
- (BOOL)hasMore;
- (id)peek;
@end

@implementation PMParser
...
@end
```

In my parse method:

```
PKAssembly*     a     = [PKTokenAssembly assemblyWithString:s];
PKAssembly*     best  = [self bestMatchFor:a];
PMParseNode*    node  = nil;
BOOL            error = NO;
NSUInteger      errorOffset = 0;

if (best == nil)  // Anything recognized?
{   
    error = YES;
}
else
{
    if ([best hasMore])  // Partial recognition?
    {
        PKToken*    t = [best peek];

        error       = YES;
        errorOffset = t.offset;
    }

    node = [best pop];
}
```

If an error occurred, `errorOffset` will contained the location of the unrecognized token.